# Looping through complex and nested JSON using this example json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to loop a complex/nested JSON object. I'm trying to loop `var_color.color.primary`.

Questions:

1. What causes this error?

   > Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
2. How can I output the primary?

Kindly use only vanilla Javascript.

```
Example Data
products.json file
{
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "000",
            "name": "Name 1",
            "description": "Long description 1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "001",
            "name": "Name 2",
            "description": "Long description 2",
            "var_color": {
                "_id": "12341",
                "color": {
                    "primary": "pink",
                    "secondary": "penk"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "002",
            "name": "Name 3",
            "description": "Long description 3"
        },
        {
            "_id": "003",
            "name": "Name 4",
            "description": "Long description 4",
            "var_color": {
                "_id": "12342",
                "color": {
                    "primary": "red",
                    "secondary": "rid"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "categories": []
}
```

```
// main.js

async function getData(product) {
    let response = await fetch(`./api/products/${product}`);
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
getData('products.json').then(data => {
    for (let i in data.products) {
        let all = data.products[i];
        let name = all.name;
        let description = all.description;
        console.log(name);
        console.log(description);
        for (let j in all) {
            let variantColor = all.var_color[j].primary;
            console.log(variantColor);
        }
    }
});
```

This is my current script as of the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `all.var_color` does not exist in each entry, therefore you need to check for its presence.
2. You are treating `all.var_color[j]` as if it were an array, but it is an object.

To get the primary color, replace the inner loop (`for (let j in all)`) with a simple test:

```
    if(all.var_color) {
        let variantColor = all.var_color.color.primary;
        console.log(variantColor);
    }
```

```js
var data = {
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "000",
            "name": "Name 1",
            "description": "Long description 1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "001",
            "name": "Name 2",
            "description": "Long description 2",
            "var_color": {
                "_id": "12341",
                "color": {
                    "primary": "pink",
                    "secondary": "penk"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "002",
            "name": "Name 3",
            "description": "Long description 3"
        },
        {
            "_id": "003",
            "name": "Name 4",
            "description": "Long description 4",
            "var_color": {
                "_id": "12342",
                "color": {
                    "primary": "red",
                    "secondary": "rid"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "categories": []
};

  for (let i in data.products) {
      let all = data.products[i];
      let name = all.name;
      let description = all.description;
      console.log(name);
      console.log(description);
      if(all.var_color) {
          let variantColor = all.var_color.color.primary;
          console.log(variantColor);
      }
  }
```

Comment: to get the primary color it must be `all.var_color.color.primary`

Comment: @Simon Oops, it is correct in the snippet, but wasnt in the above example

Comment: @feeela, Let me try your answer. Sorry if I need some time. I'm very new to Javascript.